# devilspie detect if application was started with a flag

Tags: process, arguments, devilspie

How can I set devilspie to detect if an application was started with the flag `--hello-world` from terminal?

For example `window_name` detects the window title. How can transform in devilspie the following sentence: *if one of flags is `--hello-world`*?

```
(if (is (window_name) 'My-title')
    (begin
       ...
    )   
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified if you are using the obsolete [`devilspie`](https://wiki.gnome.org/DevilsPie) or the newer [`devilspie2`](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/). In any case, as far as I can tell from their manuals, neither one of them has access to the information you want.

`Devilspie` is a window matching utility, it interacts with the X server. The commandline switches you give when you launch a program are not passed to the X server since they only affect the way the program is launched and are internal switches of that particular piece of software.

The closest seems to be the `get_application_name()` call but I doubt that would include the command line arguments. You might be able to do what you need using `xdotool` (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85205/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-a-close-event-on-various-windows-using-the-terminal)) and parsing the output of `ps aux` or `pgrep -al $APP_NAME`.

References:

- [`devislpie` manual](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie)
- [`devislpie2` manual](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/manual.php)